# how to create a drop down menu for "region" selection Tableau of the excel sheet has mulltiple citites in the cell?

Tags: excel, tableau-api

I have an excel sheet for job openings in various cities, based on fields like IT, Software, etc.

I have a bar plot with

```
Y axis = no of job opening ( 1,3, 10 etc.)
X axis = job sector (IT, Software, Hotel Management etc.)
```

I also have a column (called Location) in the excel sheet which tells me where is the company situated (New York, Beijing etc)

But the problem is that in the Location field, there are entries like the following:

```
Index |Name | No of Positions | Location | Sector
1| Alpha| 21 |Kolkata, New Delhi| Software
2| BDL | 1 | Tokyo | Concultancy
3| Quantiphi | 3 | Paris | Data Analytics
...
```

How to deal with the 1st row data? Thanks!

Comment: [This Sub Is What I use for issues like this](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/869063-duplicate-rows-separate-comma-delimited-list-last-cell.html). 

Essentially split on the delimiated value and make a duplicate row.

Comment: Wow that's a great idea